# Fail to connect to Spark with sparklyr

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparklyr

I am trying to connect to spark using sparklyr package in R and I am getting the following error:

```
    library(sparklyr)
> library(dplyr)

> config <- spark_config()

> config[["sparklyr.shell.conf"]] <- "spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-XX:MaxHeapSize=4g"

> sc <- spark_connect(master = "local",version = "1.6.2")

Error in force(code) : 
  Failed while connecting to sparklyr to port (8880) for sessionid (344): Gateway in port (8880) did not respond.
    Path: C:\Users\krispra\AppData\Local\rstudio\spark\Cache\spark-1.6.2-bin-hadoop2.6\bin\spark-submit2.cmd
    Parameters: --class, sparklyr.Backend, --jars, "C:/Users/krispra/Documents/R/R-3.3.2/library/sparklyr/java/spark-csv_2.11-1.3.0.jar","C:/Users/krispra/Documents/R/R-3.3.2/library/sparklyr/java/commons-csv-1.1.jar","C:/Users/krispra/Documents/R/R-3.3.2/library/sparklyr/java/univocity-parsers-1.5.1.jar", "C:\Users\krispra\Documents\R\R-3.3.2\library\sparklyr\java\sparklyr-1.6-2.10.jar", 8880, 344


---- Output Log ----
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for 1048576KB object heap

---- Error Log ----
```

Any suggestion how to solve it?

Thanks!
Rami

Comment: Do you want to use SparkR using RStudio? One thing is make sure that your standalone spark or spark cluster should up and running in backend.

Comment: The default port for spark is 8080 and it seems to be spark is not up and running.

Answer (score 1):

I had issue while I installed sparklyr before. The solution for me was to remove the sparklyr library and re-install via CRAN, then re-start Rstudio.